# Как различить два тэга p по позиции в которой они появляются на странице?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть два тэга p которые идут в последовательности, нужно сделать проверку на правильность этой последовальности. Сделал проверку по textContent, но при не правильной последовательности всё равно проверка срабатывает успешно т.к. ей не важно в какой они последовальности

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    const hello = '<p id="idHello">hello</p>'
    const world = '<p id="idWorld">world</p>'
    const button = '<button id="idButton" onclick="showanything()"> BUTTON </button>'

    var click = function click() {
      document.getElementById('idButton').click()
    }

    var showanything = function showanything() {
      alert('Вы нажали на кнопку')
    }

    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      setTimeout(() => {
        document.write(hello)

        resolve(setTimeout(() => {
          document.write(world)
        }, 2000))
      }, 700)
    })


    promise.then(() => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.write(button)
          resolve()
        }, 3000)
      }).then(click)
    })
  </script>

  <script>
    let checkTimer = setTimeout(function tick() {
      // i ++
      // console.log(i)

      const p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

          resolve(idHello, idWorld)

        })
        .then(function(idHello) {

          if (idHello.textContent == 'hello') {
            console.log('hello')
          }
          return idWorld

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('Ошибка')
        })
        .then(function(idWorld) {

          if (idWorld.textContent == 'world') {
            console.log('world')
            console.log('нашел параграф')
            clearTimeout(checkTimer)
          }
        })

      checkTimer = setTimeout(tick, 1000)
    }, 1000)
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Попробуйте [Node.compareDocumentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getElementsByTagName('p'), найти `<p>` с нужными вам айдишниками, сравнить индексы. Чей индекс больше, тот и позже.